# Add svg to an html table (instead of html body)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have an animated svg in the html body but I want to have it in a table cell (4x4 table) instead.

As far as I understand this is what links my svg to html body:

```
d3.xml("field.svg", function(xml) {    
svgdom = document.body.appendChild(xml.documentElement);
```

How can I link my svg to a table cell (id='c1') instead of html body?

```
<table id='tbl'>
    <tr>
        <td id='c1'></td>
        <td id='c2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='c3'></td>
        <td id='c4'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `svgdom = document.getElementById('c1').appendChild(xml.documentElement)`

Instead of `document.body`, this line of code specifically queries the document for the element you'd like to append the child to.